# Pygame : Enemy movement loops

Tags: python, pygame

I'd like to have the enemy doing the same thing in loop : it goes left to x = 150 and then goes right to x = 1300. But when the player moves, the background moves also, and I want the enemy to go right and left between to specific points on the background, and not between the two coordinates of the game window.
It's hard to explain, so ask if you want something more precise.
I don't really know what code I need to show, so here's the code for player movement and enemy movement :

```
bg_speed = 0
player_speed = 100
enemy_speed = 80

#Enemy
if enemy_animation:
    win.blit(enemy[enemycount//3], (enemyX, enemyY)) 
    enemycount += 1

    if enemy_vel > 0:
        if enemyX >= 1300:
            enemy_vel = -1
        else:
            if left == True and playerX <= 100:
                enemyX += (enemy_speed + player_speed) * dt
            elif left == True and playerX > 100:
                enemyX += (enemy_speed + (player_speed / 5)) * dt
            elif right == True and playerX >= 1350:
                enemyX += (enemy_speed - player_speed) * dt
            elif right == True and playerX < 1350:
                enemyX += (enemy_speed - (player_speed / 5)) * dt
            else:
                enemyX += enemy_speed * dt
    elif enemy_vel < 0:
        if enemyX <= 150:
            enemy_vel = 1
        else:
            if left == True and playerX <= 100:
                enemyX -= (enemy_speed - player_speed) * dt
            elif left == True and playerX > 100:
                enemyX -= (enemy_speed - (player_speed / 5)) * dt
            elif right == True and playerX >= 1350:
                enemyX -= (enemy_speed + player_speed) * dt
            elif right == True and playerX < 1350:
                enemyX -= (enemy_speed + (player_speed / 5)) * dt
            else:
                enemyX -= enemy_speed * dt

#Player :
if left:
    win.blit(walkLeft[walkcount//1], (playerX-20,playerY))

    if playerX > 100:
        playerX -= (player_speed + (player_speed / 5)) * dt  #vitesse du joueur = 1/3
        backgroundX += (player_speed / 5) * dt #vitesse du fond d'écran = 2/3
        if playerX == 100: 
            playerX -= 0
            backgroundX += player_speed * dt
    else:
        backgroundX += player_speed * dt

elif right:
    win.blit(walkRight[walkcount//1], (playerX-50,playerY))

    if playerX < 1350:
        playerX += (player_speed + (player_speed / 5)) * dt
        backgroundX -= (player_speed / 5) * dt
        if playerX == 1350:
            playerX += 0
            backgroundX -= player_speed * dt
    else:
        backgroundX -= player_speed * dt
```

Comment: you have to define `offset` on which moves background and use it to correct enemy  position. So ie. if you move background `5px` left then you have to also move enemy (and other object) `5px` left.

Comment: BTW: you could use Player position to calculate `offset` and make all other  calculations without moving background, and add offset only when you draw objects (but not add it to original objects' position) - ie. `blit(background, (0+offsetX, 0+offsetY)` `blit(player, (playerX+offsetX, playerY+offsetY))` `blit(enemy, (enemyX+offsetX, enemyY+offsetY))`

Comment: if I'm not wrong it is called `scrolling camera`.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as there is no [**Minimal**, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to make a function (I called it «camera_enemy ») that returns the value of `enemy.pos.x+background.pos.x`. Then, when blitting the enemy, write `win.blit(enemy_img, (camera_enemy, enemy.pos.y))`